# Oracle Apex - getting form fields fixed while changing the values of others

Tags: javascript, html, css, oracle-apex

Good evening!

I work in Oracle Apex 4.2 and I have the following task. I should create a form which looks like this:

Company:   [company ^]
Branch:       [branch ^]        Employee:             [employee ^]
Address:     [address]         Phone number:     [phone number]

The fields "Company", "Branch" and "Employee" are select lists, and "Address" and "Phone number" are text fiels. Values of "Branch" field depend on the value selected from "Company" (due to using of "Cascading LOV"), the same behaviour has "Employee" for "Branch". So to say about "Address" and "Phone number", they should be filled manually.

I've created this form and it works fine except one little but disgusting thing. When I change the value of "Company", the part with "Branch" field is getting a bit more tight in its height while the values for its select list are loading (though request for data is very fast). And when I do the same with "Branch", the fields "Employee" and "Phone number" are twitching along their length during the reloading of content of "Employee" select list.

I've tried to solve my problem with setting column width by means of CSS and HTML (like *width='300px'* or *style="padding-right:10px;"*) and managing columns span, but it helps me not in all the cases. For example, I have another form with similar logic, but it contains two more fields (let them be named "Branch2" and "Employee2") which behaviour is like the ones of "Branch" and "Employee". And when I change the value of "Branch", "Employee2" (not related to "Branch") is twitching even after I've tried to do something with the help of CSS and HTML.

All I know is that when data is loading in select lists, a small round progress bar shows up during the process. Also, it's undesirable to change the relative positions of the fields (they are aligned in necessary for the form way). So, what should I do to make my form not to twitch during the changing of field values?

Comment: what do you mean by "twitching"?

Comment: When I don't do anything with the form, all the fields keep fixed. But when I'm changing the value, for example, of "Company", the fields depending on it are shaking for a moment (and round progress bar is shown).

Comment: as long as you want those lists updated depending on the prior, that behavior is necessary. But if you don't want the rest of the items accompanying that update you could set the Address item to start a new grid.

Comment: Thank you very much for this advice. Though now I have other problem - aligning grids in that way so the fields could be aligned precisely, - you helped me a lot. :-) So to say about me, I should learn CSS much better.